# React - Multiple Ajax Calls to API

Tags: ajax, reactjs, promise

I want to make an api call to fetch an array of vehicles.
Once that is achieved i want to loop through the array and make a call to the API for each vehicle details.

i.e 2 API endpoints

/vehicles

/vehicles/{id}

What is the best way to do this in React?
Also, preferably using fetch/await

Comment: it sounds like you have an idea of how you want to do this (using fetch/await). What's the issue you're having? Some code would be really helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to do this with Promises.
Initially you fetch your data and then using `Promise.all()` and `Array.map()` loop trough  array items and fetch details for them (in parallel).

```
fetch('https://my-json-server.typicode.com/typicode/demo/posts')
 .then(res => res.json())
 .then(async data => {
      const details = await Promise.all(data.map(post => {
    return fetch(`https://my-json-server.typicode.com/typicode/demo/posts/${post.id}`)
      .then(res => res.json());
  }));
  console.log(details);
 })
```

[Link to JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8yhrb6zv/1/)